# Why is Nmap Scripting Engine returning an error?

Tags: macos, lua, nmap, port-scanning

When ever I try to run the following Nmap Command:
`nmap -sA -sV -T5 -O -A -v -Pn --script afp-brute,ajp-brute,backorifice-brute,cassandra-brute,cvs-brute,dns-brute,domcon-brute,dpap-brute,drda-brute,ftp-brute,http-adobe-coldfusion-apsa1301,http-affiliate-id,http-apache-negotiation,http-apache-server-status,http-aspnet-debug,http-auth-finder,http-auth,http-avaya-ipoffice-users,http-awstatstotals-exec,http-axis2-dir-traversal,http-backup-finder,http-barracuda-dir-traversal,http-brute,http-cakephp-version,http-chrono,http-cisco-anyconnect,http-coldfusion-subzero,http-comments-displayer,http-config-backup,http-cors,http-cross-domain-policy,http-csrf,http-date,http-default-accounts,http-devframework,http-dlink-backdoor,http-dombased-xss,http-domino-enum-passwords,http-drupal-enum-users,http-drupal-enum,http-enum,http-errors,http-exif-spider,http-favicon,http-feed,http-fetch,http-fileupload-exploiter,http-form-brute,http-form-fuzzer,http-frontpage-login,http-generator,http-git,http-gitweb-projects-enum,http-google-malware,http-grep,http-headers,http-huawei-hg5xx-vuln,http-icloud-findmyiphone,http-icloud-sendmsg,http-iis-short-name-brute,http-iis-webdav-vuln,http-internal-ip-disclosure,http-joomla-brute,http-litespeed-sourcecode-download,http-ls,http-majordomo2-dir-traversal,http-malware-host,http-mcmp,http-method-tamper,http-methods,http-mobileversion-checker,http-ntlm-info,http-open-proxy,http-open-redirect,http-passwd,http-php-version,http-phpmyadmin-dir-traversal,http-phpself-xss,http-proxy-brute,http-put,http-qnap-nas-info,http-referer-checker,http-rfi-spider,http-robots.txt,http-robtex-reverse-ip,http-robtex-shared-ns,http-server-header,http-shellshock,http-sitemap-generator,http-slowloris-check,http-slowloris,http-sql-injection,http-stored-xss,http-svn-enum,http-svn-info,http-title,http-tplink-dir-traversal,http-trace,http-traceroute,http-unsafe-output-escaping,http-useragent-tester,http-userdir-enum,http-vhosts,http-virustotal,http-vlcstreamer-ls,http-vmware-path-vuln,http-vuln-cve2006-3392,http-vuln-cve2009-3960,http-vuln-cve2010-0738,http-vuln-cve2010-2861,http-vuln-cve2011-3192,http-vuln-cve2011-3368,http-vuln-cve2012-1823,http-vuln-cve2013-0156,http-vuln-cve2013-6786,http-vuln-cve2013-7091,http-vuln-cve2014-2126,http-vuln-cve2014-2127,http-vuln-cve2014-2128,http-vuln-cve2014-2129,http-vuln-cve2014-3704,http-vuln-cve2014-8877,http-vuln-cve2015-1427,http-vuln-cve2015-1635,http-vuln-misfortune-cookie,http-vuln-wnr1000-creds,http-waf-detect,http-waf-fingerprint,http-webdav-scan,http-wordpress-brute,http-wordpress-enum,http-wordpress-users,http-xssed,iax2-brute,imap-brute,informix-brute,ip-forwarding,ip-geolocation-geoplugin,ip-geolocation-ipinfodb,ip-geolocation-map-bing,ip-geolocation-map-google,ip-geolocation-map-kml,ip-geolocation-maxmind,ip-https-discover,ipidseq,ipmi-brute,ipmi-cipher-zero,ipmi-version,ipv6-multicast-mld-list,ipv6-node-info,ipv6-ra-flood,irc-brute,irc-sasl-brute,iscsi-brute,ldap-brute,membase-brute,metasploit-msgrpc-brute,metasploit-xmlrpc-brute,mikrotik-routeros-brute,mmouse-brute,mongodb-brute,ms-sql-brute,mysql-brute,nessus-brute,nessus-xmlrpc-brute,netbus-brute,nexpose-brute,nje-node-brute,nje-pass-brute,nping-brute,omp2-brute,openvas-otp-brute,oracle-brute,oracle-sid-brute,pcanywhere-brute,pgsql-brute,pop3-brute,redis-brute,rexec-brute,rlogin-brute,rpcap-brute,rsync-brute,rtsp-url-brute,sip-brute,smb-brute,smtp-brute,snmp-brute,socks-brute,svn-brute,targets-asn,targets-ipv6-map4to6,targets-ipv6-multicast-echo,targets-ipv6-multicast-invalid-dst,targets-ipv6-multicast-mld,targets-ipv6-multicast-slaac,targets-ipv6-wordlist,targets-sniffer,targets-traceroute,targets-xml,telnet-brute,telnet-encryption,telnet-ntlm-info,traceroute-geolocation,tso-brute,unusual-port,vmauthd-brute,vnc-brute,whois-domain,whois-ip,xmpp-brute, 192.168.1.226`

I get this error:

```
    NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
   /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:840: assertion failed!
    stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:840: in local     'get_chosen_scripts'
        /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1271: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

QUITTING!
```

Why could this be? I have never had any problem with this before. This is the newest verison of nmap with all excesories installed as well. I am running it on mac osx and it was installed with homebrew.

Comment: Unneeded comma before IP?

Comment: Wow, a kilometer of parameters!  Have you tried cutting down the parameter list until perhaps the problem disappears?  This can only go two ways: If the problem does indeed disappear then you have found the cause of it, but what's best is that if there is still a problem you will have presented your case with a lot less 'garbage' for the rest of us to go through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crash is caused by the trailing comma in your scripts list. An empty rule (like the one "following" that extra comma) is being interpreted as a directory with no name, which is then interpreted as the default scripts directory. Then, since some of the same scripts are chosen by name and by directory, the assertion that no 2 scripts have the same ID (basename) fails. I've corrected these problems in development, so look for them in the next release of Nmap:

- r36761: Avoid empty rules interpreted as all scripts in the script dir.
- r36762: Clarify an assertion